# WinRT : How to handle errors at Facebook Login Button Click?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-8, windows-runtime, facebook-login

I'd like to know what is the approach of making some error handling to the login action of the `Facebook Login button`. Cause, I've acquired the APP ID, and everything is OK, I can log in and out and that stuff.

But, if I disconnect from the internet, things are going wild. I've tried on login button's `Tapped` event, but I get `WebExceptionWrapper` (The remote name could not be resolved: 'graph.facebook.com').

I've also tried on `UserSessionStateChanged` event but it also seems it is not the case.

There is also an `Authentication Error` event but it doesn't get triggered ...

How should I prevent the login process if there is no internet connection available?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to find any answer so I'll go the ugly path : I'll go with an implementation consisting of global exception handling...